# Inherit a class across modules?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, module

We have a class Car defined like this in a car.rb file

```
class Car
end
```

then, we have another class Car defined in electric/car.rb

```
require "../car.rb"
module Electric
  class Car < Car
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, it seems that we can't inherit from the first class. Why is that?

Comment: You cannot name the derived class `Car`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid any ambiguity by using the fully qualified name of Car:

```
module Electric
  class Car < ::Car
  end
end
```

Comment: Good! That's what I was looking for ;)